# how to close a while statement in bc script

Tags: shell-script, bc

I cannot find a way to close while statement.The following is my bash script code.

```
bc << EOF
a=0;
while(a<10) a++;

print a;
EOF
```

The ouput is not as expected, it prints all the `a` values other than the last one. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of an operation is always printed unless it's an assignment.  So, let's turn `a++` into the assignment `a=a+1`.

```
bc <<END_BC
a = 0
while (a < 10) a = a + 1
print a, "\n"
END_BC
```

Alternatively, but slightly more cryptic (using an empty while loop):

```
bc <<END_BC
a = 0
while (++a < 10)
print a, "\n"
END_BC
```